Getting 404 Error After Adding New Controller in Yii2 Advanced Project
I've been trying to set up my Yii2 advanced project, and after adding a new controller in the backend application, I'm getting a 404 error. Here is my controller class:
What else do I need to configure to solve the issue? My server is working properly, and the default configurations are running well in the browser.
<?php
namespace backend\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}

I've tried restarting my Apache server, but it still isn't working
